# i want to replace particular pixel color in vc++ using opencv and store that new image on disk

Tags: exception, opencv

this is my coding part

this is my code block

I'm getting `System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException @  cvSaveImage("foo.jpg",depth_ipl);`

I have also used   `cv::imwrite("E:\image1.jpg",depth_ipl);` instead of `cvSaveImage("foo.jpg",depth_ipl);`

it gives me `System.AccessViolationException`.

please help.

```
  #include "stdafx.h"
  #include <tchar.h>
  #include <cv.h>
  #include <cxcore.h>
  #include <highgui.h>
  #include <iostream>

 using namespace cv;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{       
    cv::Mat3b image =cv::imread("image.jpg");


    for(Mat3b::iterator it=image.begin(); it!=image.end();it++)
    {
        if(*it==Vec3b(255,255,255))
        {
            (*it=Vec3b(0,0,255));
        }
    }
    IplImage* depth_ipl = new IplImage(image);


    cvSaveImage("foo.jpg",depth_ipl);

    return 0;
```

}

Comment: please somebody help me!!!!

Comment: check if image's data is valid (NULL) and after this process image.

Comment: thank you for reply my image was null since my url is not proper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My best guess is that you need to change the line:

```
cv::imwrite("E:\image1.jpg",depth_ipl);
```

to

```
cv::imwrite("E:\\image1.jpg",image); // notice the double backslash
```